# Flask and javascript to MySQL

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, flask

I'm starting to create a simple flask powered web page. 
The webpage task is a simple button and will update the status
on mysql whenever it change it's color status when pressed.

But i'm kinda new to flask framework and don't know how to inject the right code
to achieved the situation combined with javascript. Hope someone can help or demo on how to do this, Or some instruction steps to show.

Here is my sample code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def sample():
    return render_template('button.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8001,debug=True)
```

my sample button.html under templates folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#000000"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" id="button" value = "button" style= "color:white;background-color: #000000;" onclick="setColor('button')";/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to handle it. A simple way would be to create a javascript function like such:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
       $("#flaskRoute").onclick("#divID");
   });
</script>
```

Your HTML is pretty simple. Notice the id="divID" locations.

```
<input type="button" id="divID" value = "button" style= 
"color:white;background-color: #000000;" onclick="setColor('button')";/>
```

In the javascript before we used #flaskRoute. This will call the Flask route. I don't know what you are using in mysql for tables, and fields so I just made some stuff up.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "username", "password", "DB")

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/flaskRoute')
def put(self, color):
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT tablename SET color = %s WHERE fieldname = %s"
        cursor.execute(sql, (color, fieldname))
        db.commit()
        return render_template('button.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

This is an example code to insert something into the database, you can do an update if you already know what colors you have defined. You can also use this same method to query the database on load of the webpage to get the current color set in the database.